# Sybase server linked in SSMS using Concatenate in openquery

Tags: concatenation, sybase, ssms, openquery

I have managed to link a Sybase server to SSMS and am able to query it using openquery but I get an error every time I try to concatenate columns.  ie:

```
Select * from openquery(SybaseServer, 'select top 1000 first_name + middle_name + Last_name as "full_name", * from dbname..tablename')
```

I realize this won't put a space between the names which is fine as I'm just using that as an example.

My thought is either it's something weird with the Sybase syntax or it's the structure of the open query.  I know that within the open query I need to use " " instead of ' ' so is there a trick to getting concatenate to work?  Sorry if this is basic but googled for about 30 mins and nothing directly answered my question.  I don't think it's the Sybase syntax from what I have read so gotta be the openquery structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

realized the columns needed to be converted to same data type...  added conversions and good ole fashioned + worked.